# Displaying a rendered content of .org file into the terminal

Tags: org-mode

I got a zsh script which do some work for me. Somewhere in the body of that script I'd like to have nicely rendered .org file displayed, and my zsh script to continue further. In sudo code something like that

```
...
do something   #(and display something in stdout)
...
display in stdout rendered .org file #(without stopping the script)
...
do something   #(and display something in stdout)
...
```

To display the content of my org file I tried:

- cat – but it doesn't recognise the org syntax,
- mdless – but it recognise the org syntax partially (designed for .md not .org),
- bat – almost works, recognise the syntax, but stops the script.

None of the above worked for me.

Therefore, I thought maybe there is a nice emacs CLI command which does it for me?

Or I could perhaps call emacs to be opened in separate process and open that file for me in the frame of specific size, with the check not open the .org file twice?

Could you guys advise me on the above?

Comment: Maybe try `pandoc`?

Comment: What do you mean by "rendered .org file"? That it should look the same way that it appears when you open the file in Emacs (i.e. with the same fontification)? If so, I don't know of a way to do it (other than opening it in Emacs and setting its mode to Org mode).

Comment: @NickD Yes, that what I mean. With the .md files you can do it using mdless md cat bat, and I'm wondering how to do it using emacs

Comment: AFAIK, what you want is not possible: fontification requires Emacs and the Org mode initializations of fontification, so you cannot get the same effect outside that framework.